# How to set up the boundary between volumes in a simulated turbine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, turbines, cfd

I am simulating a turbine and I have some doubts about the correctness of my approach.

In this turbine, there are three volumes:

[image]

The two volumes are the piping before and after the blade and the other volume contains the turbine blades. The domain containing the blades rotates at 2000 rpm = 209.43 rad/s while the other two volumes are stationary.

I modeled this turbine in Gambit.

In this case, are there any problems? Gambit is weak for modeling this stage.